# JTextArea txt; txt.getText() skips "\n"

Tags: java, swing, io

i have some text in TextArea, and i want to save it in file, my code is here:

```
private void SaveFile() {
    try {

        String content = txt.getText();

        File file = new File(filename);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

but it saves without "\n"; and in new file everything is on one line;
ho can i foresee those "enters"  too?
thank you in advance

the problem was because of notepad, so here is solution:

```
private void SaveFile() {
    try {

        String content = txt.getText();
        content = content.replaceAll("(?!\\r)\\n", "\r\n");

        File file = new File(filename);

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Could you share the output of `txt.getText();`?

Comment: How do you verify this skipped '\n'. Some text editors (grrr notepad) ksip \n in favour of carriage returns (\r) Try another text editor.

Comment: \n is considered as new line. So try to add it by appending with the escape character like \\n

Comment: Quirliom - u were right. thank u

Comment: @Quirliom  Perhaps you should put that as an answer.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but a simpler way to write a JTextArea to a file is to use its `write` method: `txt.write(new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile())`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write(java.io.Writer)
 but then of course you can not change the content to add the `\r\n`.

Comment: @CyrilleKa, you can control the newline string when using the write() method. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work. Try to use a text editor that display the line endings \r and \n and see what comes up.

If you want to be sure that the text file can be open by windows utilities like Notepad that only understand `\r\n`, you have to normalize it yourself this way:

```
content = content.replaceAll("(?!\\r)\\n", "\r\n");
```

This will replace all `\n` who is not preceded by a `\r` by the sequence `\r\n`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the read() and write() methods provided by the Swing text components. See [Text and New Lines](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) for more information.

If you want the output to contain a specific EOL string then you should use the following after creating the Document for your text component:

```
textComponent.getDocument().putProperty(DefaultEditorKit.EndOfLineStringProperty, "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

The \ character escapes the next character, as you say \n will create a newline. If you wish to output an actual \, you need to write:

"\n"

Comment: i opend my save file in notepad, and it showed me on one line..
but when i open it in other editor, it whos me "enters" too, so it was notepad-s fault :D

Comment: save data in \\n  in textarea

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PrintWriter` to print new Line to a file . On scanning TextArea's text if the TextArea's text contains "\\n" then use PrintWriter's `println`() method else make use of simply `print`() !

Answer (score 0):

You have the content of your TextArea in a String. Now you can split it at newline, then you will get your String[]. Then you can iterate the String[] array and write it in your file:

```
private void SaveFile() {
        try {
            String content = txt.getText();
            File file = new File(filename);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for (String line : content.split("\\n")) {
                bw.write(content);
            }

            bw.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```