# ServerGUI with Save Log - JAVA

Tags: java, swing, logging, client, server

So what I have tried to do is a server with a client. Where the server starts a server and the client opens the chat-room where he can write anything he want.

So I have 2 problems that I cant get it to work.

1. First problem is that I cant make it save automaticlly as a .txt. I need to write always at the end .txt to make it save
2. When im saving it as a .txt. It saves everything in a row. So it doesn't look good.

[image: The problem]

**How I want it to be**
[image: How I want it to be.]

So yes. I would apperciate all help to make it work as I want.

Greetings

Thrillofit

**CODE**

**ServerGUI**

```
    package Server;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

/*
 * The server as a GUI
 */
public class ServerGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener, WindowListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // the stop and start buttons
    private JButton stopStart, saveLog;
    // JTextArea for the chat room and the events
    private JTextArea chat;
    // private JTextArea event;
    // The port number
    private JTextField tfPortNumber;
    // my server
    private Server server;

    // server constructor that receive the port to listen to for connection as
    // parameter
    ServerGUI(int port) {
        super("Chat Server");
        server = null;
        // in the NorthPanel the PortNumber the Start and Stop buttons
        JPanel north = new JPanel();
        north.add(new JLabel("Port number: "));
        tfPortNumber = new JTextField("" + port);
        north.add(tfPortNumber);
        // to stop or start the server, we start with "Start"
        stopStart = new JButton("Start");
        stopStart.addActionListener(this);
        saveLog = new JButton("Save log");
        saveLog.addActionListener(this);
        north.add(stopStart);
        north.add(saveLog);
        add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        // the event and chat room
        JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        chat = new JTextArea(120, 20);
        chat.setEditable(false);
        chat.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        chat.setLineWrap(true);
        appendRoom(null, "Chat room and Events log for server.\n");
        center.add(new JScrollPane(chat));
        // event = new JTextArea(80,80);
        // event.setEditable(false);
        // appendEvent("Events log.\n");
        // center.add(new JScrollPane(event));
        add(center);
        // need to be informed when the user click the close button on the frame
        addWindowListener(this);
        setSize(450, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void writeLog() throws IOException {
        String saveText = chat.getText();   
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
//      chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("./"));
        int actionDialog = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
        if (actionDialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File fileName = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile() + "");
            if (fileName == null)
                return;
            if (fileName.exists()) {
                actionDialog = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,
                        "Replace existing file?");
                if (actionDialog == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                    return;
            }
            try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream(fileName), "ISO-8859-1"))) {
                bw.write(saveText);
//              bw.newLine();
                bw.flush(); 
            }
        }
    }


    // append message to the two JTextArea
    // position at the end
    void appendRoom(String chatStr, String eventStr) {
        chat.append(chatStr);
        chat.append(eventStr);
//      chat.setCaretPosition(chat.getText().length() - 1);
    }

    // void appendEvent(String str) {
    // event.append(str);
    // event.setCaretPosition(chat.getText().length() - 1);
    //
    // }

    // start or stop where clicked
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // if running we have to stop
        if (e.getSource() == saveLog) {
            try {
                writeLog();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (e.getSource() == stopStart) {
            if (server != null) {
                server.stop();
                server = null;
                tfPortNumber.setEditable(true);
                stopStart.setText("Start");
                return;
            }
            // OK start the server
            int port;
            try {
                port = Integer.parseInt(tfPortNumber.getText().trim());
            } catch (Exception er) {
                appendRoom(null, "Invalid port number");
                return;
            }
            // ceate a new Server
            server = new Server(port, this);
            // and start it as a thread
            new ServerRunning().start();
            stopStart.setText("Stop");
            tfPortNumber.setEditable(false);
        }
    }
    /*
     * A thread to run the Server
     */
    class ServerRunning extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            server.start(); // should execute until if fails
            // the server failed
            stopStart.setText("Start");
            tfPortNumber.setEditable(true);
            appendRoom(null, "Server closed\n");
            server = null;
        }
    }

    // entry point to start the Server
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        // start server default port 1500
        new ServerGUI(1500);
    }

    /*
     * If the user click the X button to close the application I need to close
     * the connection with the server to free the port
     */
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // if my Server exist
        if (server != null) {
            try {
                server.stop(); // ask the server to close the conection
            } catch (Exception eClose) {
            }
            server = null;
        }
        // dispose the frame
        dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // I can ignore the other WindowListener method
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }

//  /*
//   * A thread to run the Server
//   */
//  class ServerRunning extends Thread {
//      public void run() {
//          server.start(); // should execute until if fails
//          // the server failed
//          stopStart.setText("Start");
//          tfPortNumber.setEditable(true);
//          appendRoom(null, "Server closed\n");
//          server = null;
//      }
//  }
}
```

I think its the only code that needs this. If not, just tell me.

**UPDATE 1:**

**ClientGUI.java**

```
 package Server;
import javax.swing.*;


/*
 * The Client with its GUI
 */
public class ClientGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JLabel lblusername;

    private JTextField textfieldusername, textfieldserver, textfieldportnumber;

    private JButton btnlogin, btnlogout, btnonline;

    private JTextArea textareamessage;

    private boolean connected;

    private Client client;

    private int defaultPort;
    private String defaultHost;


    ClientGUI(String host, int port) {

        super("Chat Client");
        defaultPort = port;
        defaultHost = host;


        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        JPanel serverAndPort = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2, 2, 2));
        JLabel lblserveraddress = new JLabel("Server Address:  ");
        JLabel lblchat = new JLabel("                #BallIsLife");
        JLabel lblportnumber = new JLabel("Port Number:  ");

        textfieldserver = new JTextField(host);
        textfieldserver.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        textfieldserver.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        textfieldportnumber = new JTextField("" + port);
        textfieldportnumber.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        textfieldportnumber.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);

        lblserveraddress.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 19));
        serverAndPort.add(lblserveraddress);
        serverAndPort.add(textfieldserver);
        serverAndPort.add(lblchat);
        serverAndPort.add(lblportnumber);
        serverAndPort.add(textfieldportnumber);
        lblchat.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblportnumber.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 19));
        northPanel.add(serverAndPort);
        getContentPane().add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel panelbtn = new JPanel();
        northPanel.add(panelbtn);


        btnlogin = new JButton("Login");
        panelbtn.add(btnlogin);
        btnlogin.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        btnlogin.addActionListener(this);

        btnonline = new JButton("Online");
        panelbtn.add(btnonline);
        btnonline.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));

        btnonline.addActionListener(this);
        btnonline.setEnabled(false);        

        btnlogout = new JButton("Logout");
        panelbtn.add(btnlogout);
        btnlogout.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        btnlogout.addActionListener(this);
        btnlogout.setEnabled(false);        

        JButton btnPicture = new JButton("Picture");
        btnPicture.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        btnPicture.setEnabled(false);
        panelbtn.add(btnPicture);


        textareamessage = new JTextArea("Welcome to the #BallIsLife Chat room.\n");
        textareamessage.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 15));

        textareamessage.setLineWrap(true);
        textareamessage.setEditable(false);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textareamessage);
        centerPanel.add(scrollPane);
        getContentPane().add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        lblusername = new JLabel("Enter your username", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblusername.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        southPanel.add(lblusername);

        textfieldusername = new JTextField("Write your username here.");
        textfieldusername.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        textfieldusername.setColumns(50);

        southPanel.add(textfieldusername);


        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(823, 665);
        setVisible(true);

    }

//Logiken

    void append(String str) {
        textareamessage.append(str);
        textareamessage.setCaretPosition(textareamessage.getText().length() - 1);
    }


    void connectionFailed() {
        btnlogin.setEnabled(true);
        btnlogout.setEnabled(false);
        btnonline.setEnabled(false);
        lblusername.setText("Enter your username");
        textfieldusername.setText("Write your username here");

        textfieldportnumber.setText("" + defaultPort);
        textfieldserver.setText(defaultHost);

        textfieldserver.setEditable(false);
        textfieldportnumber.setEditable(false);

        textfieldusername.removeActionListener(this);
        connected = false;
    }

    //

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object button = e.getSource();

        if(button == btnlogout) {
            client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.LOGOUT, "")); //Ändra till Chatmessage klass
            btnlogin.setText("Login");
            return;
        }

        if(button == btnonline) {
            client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.WHOISIN, ""));   //Ändra till Chatmessage klass          
            return;
        }


        if(connected) {

            client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.MESSAGE, textfieldusername.getText())); //Ändra till Chatmessage klass       
            textfieldusername.setText("");
            return;
        }


        if(button == btnlogin) {

            String username = textfieldusername.getText();

            if(username.length() == 0)
                return;

            String server = textfieldserver.getText();
            if(server.length() == 0)
                return;

            String portNumber = textfieldportnumber.getText();
            if(portNumber.length() == 0)
                return;


            int port = 0;
            try {
                port = Integer.parseInt(portNumber);
            }
            catch(Exception en) {
                return;  
            }


            client = new Client(server, port, username, this);

            if(!client.start()) 
                return;

            }

            connected = true;

            textfieldusername.setText("");
            btnlogin.setText("Send message");


            btnlogin.setEnabled(true);

            btnlogout.setEnabled(true);
            btnonline.setEnabled(true);

            textfieldserver.setEditable(false);
            textfieldportnumber.setEditable(false);

            textfieldusername.addActionListener(this);
        }



    // to start the whole thing the server
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClientGUI("localhost", 1500);
    }

}
```

**Server.java**

```
    package Server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

/*
 * The server that can be run both as a console application or a GUI
 */
public class Server {
    // a unique ID for each connection
    private static int uniqueId;
    // an ArrayList to keep the list of the Client
    private ArrayList<ClientThread> al;
    // if I am in a GUI
    private ServerGUI sg;
    // to display time
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    // the port number to listen for connection
    private int port;
    // the boolean that will be turned of to stop the server
    private boolean keepGoing;


    /*
     *  server constructor that receive the port to listen to for connection as parameter
     *  in console
     */
    public Server(int port) {
        this(port, null);
    }

    public Server(int port, ServerGUI sg) {
        // GUI or not
        this.sg = sg;
        // the port
        this.port = port;
        // to display hh:mm:ss
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        // ArrayList for the Client list
        al = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
    }

    public void start() {
        keepGoing = true;
        /* create socket server and wait for connection requests */
        try 
        {
            // the socket used by the server
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

            // infinite loop to wait for connections
            while(keepGoing) 
            {
                // format message saying we are waiting
                display("Server waiting for Clients on port " + port + ".");

                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();      // accept connection
                // if I was asked to stop
                if(!keepGoing)
                    break;
                ClientThread t = new ClientThread(socket);  // make a thread of it
                al.add(t);                                  // save it in the ArrayList
                t.start();
            }
            // I was asked to stop
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
                for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i) {
                    ClientThread tc = al.get(i);
                    try {
                    tc.sInput.close();
                    tc.sOutput.close();
                    tc.socket.close();
                    }
                    catch(IOException ioE) {
                        // not much I can do
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                display("Exception closing the server and clients: " + e);
            }
        }
        // something went bad
        catch (IOException e) {
            String msg = sdf.format(new Date()) + " Exception on new ServerSocket: " + e + "\n";
            display(msg);
        }
    }       
    /*
     * For the GUI to stop the server
     */
    protected void stop() {
        keepGoing = false;
        // connect to myself as Client to exit statement 
        // Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        try {
            new Socket("localhost", port);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            // nothing I can really do
        }
    }
    /*
     * Display an event (not a message) to the console or the GUI
     */
    private void display(String msg) {
        String time = sdf.format(new Date()) + " " + msg;
        if(sg == null)
            System.out.println(time);
        else
            sg.appendRoom(null,time + "\n");
    }
    /*
     *  to broadcast a message to all Clients
     */
    private synchronized void broadcast(String message) {
        // add HH:mm:ss and \n to the message
        String time = sdf.format(new Date());
        String messageLf = time + " " + message + "\n";
        // display message on console or GUI
        if(sg == null)
            System.out.print(messageLf);
        else
            sg.appendRoom(messageLf,null);     // append in the room window

        // we loop in reverse order in case we would have to remove a Client
        // because it has disconnected
        for(int i = al.size(); --i >= 0;) {
            ClientThread ct = al.get(i);
            // try to write to the Client if it fails remove it from the list
            if(!ct.writeMsg(messageLf)) {
                al.remove(i);
                display("Disconnected Client " + ct.username + " removed from list.");
            }
        }
    }

    // for a client who logoff using the LOGOUT message
    synchronized void remove(int id) {
        // scan the array list until we found the Id
        for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i) {
            ClientThread ct = al.get(i);
            // found it
            if(ct.id == id) {
                al.remove(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     *  To run as a console application just open a console window and: 
     * > java Server
     * > java Server portNumber
     * If the port number is not specified 1500 is used
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start server on port 1500 unless a PortNumber is specified 
        int portNumber = 1500;
        switch(args.length) {
            case 1:
                try {
                    portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid port number.");
                    System.out.println("Usage is: > java Server [portNumber]");
                    return;
                }
            case 0:
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Usage is: > java Server [portNumber]");
                return;

        }
        // create a server object and start it
        Server server = new Server(portNumber);
        server.start();
    }

    /** One instance of this thread will run for each client */
    class ClientThread extends Thread {
        // the socket where to listen/talk
        Socket socket;
        ObjectInputStream sInput;
        ObjectOutputStream sOutput;
        // my unique id (easier for deconnection)
        int id;
        // the Username of the Client
        String username;
        // the only type of message a will receive
        ChatMessage cm;
        // the date I connect
        String date;

        // Constructore
        ClientThread(Socket socket) {
            // a unique id
            id = ++uniqueId;
            this.socket = socket;
            /* Creating both Data Stream */
            System.out.println("Thread trying to create Object Input/Output Streams");
            try
            {
                // create output first
                sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                sInput  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                // read the username
                username = (String) sInput.readObject();
                display(username + " just connected.");
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                display("Exception creating new Input/output Streams: " + e);
                return;
            }
            // have to catch ClassNotFoundException
            // but I read a String, I am sure it will work
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            }
            date = new Date().toString() + "\n";
        }

        // what will run forever
        public void run() {
            // to loop until LOGOUT
            boolean keepGoing = true;
            while(keepGoing) {
                // read a String (which is an object)
                try {
                    cm = (ChatMessage) sInput.readObject();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    display(username + " Exception reading Streams: " + e);
                    break;              
                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                    break;
                }
                // the messaage part of the ChatMessage
                String message = cm.getMessage();

                // Switch on the type of message receive
                switch(cm.getType()) {

                case ChatMessage.MESSAGE:
                    broadcast(username + ": " + message);
                    break;
                case ChatMessage.LOGOUT:
                    display(username + " disconnected with a LOGOUT message.");
                    keepGoing = false;
                    break;
                case ChatMessage.WHOISIN:
                    writeMsg("List of the users connected at " + sdf.format(new Date()) + "\n");
                    // scan al the users connected
                    for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i) {
                        ClientThread ct = al.get(i);
                        writeMsg((i+1) + ") " + ct.username + " since " + ct.date);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            // remove myself from the arrayList containing the list of the
            // connected Clients
            remove(id);
            close();
        }

        // try to close everything
        private void close() {
            // try to close the connection
            try {
                if(sOutput != null) sOutput.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {}
            try {
                if(sInput != null) sInput.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {};
            try {
                if(socket != null) socket.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        /*
         * Write a String to the Client output stream
         */
        private boolean writeMsg(String msg) {
            // if Client is still connected send the message to it
            if(!socket.isConnected()) {
                close();
                return false;
            }
            // write the message to the stream
            try {
                sOutput.writeObject(msg);
            }
            // if an error occurs, do not abort just inform the user
            catch(IOException e) {
                display("Error sending message to " + username);
                display(e.toString());
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you are doing this chat.append(chatStr); The chatStr is not containing any line break character like \r or \n etc?

If JTextArea does not support holding line break characters then you can maintain a string or stringbuilder object separately than your JTextArea text field.

Then while writing to the file use that separate string object. That will allow you to save new line characters in the text file.

Comment: Okey, I will show you my ClientGUI so you can see how it sees, Look the update.

Comment: Sorry i entered text when i did not finish writing it. Its updated now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a member variable chatContent and Write a method like below to add content to it.

```
StringBuilder chatContent = new StringBuilder();

private void addText(String chatText){
    chatContent.append(chatText).append("\n");
}
```

and call it everytime you append to the chat textarea and when writing to the file use this chatContent as the source of content to be written.

Perhaps it will help.

Or you can stream your content directly to file as well in real time using a

```
FileOutputStream
```

**Update 1:**

Check this [JTextArea txt; txt.getText() skips "\n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483350/jtextarea-txt-txt-gettext-skips-n)

This might help.

**Update 2**

```
// Replace this line 

    File fileName = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile() + "");

    // With following code
    String _fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile();

    if(_fileName != null && !_fileName.endsWith(".txt")){
        _fileName = _fileName + ".txt";
    }

    File fileName = new File(_fileName);
```

Comment: So I just updated and as you see, maybe its something wrong now in a another class? Or should I go for what you recommend?

Comment: My first suggestion should work logically if getText does not return newline in it. But if it is returning new line and its just that notepad not displaying \n as a new line then please just see the link i have added to my answer. That might help.

Comment: Yaayyy it worked! Now for the other problem. How does it save automatic to a .txt without adding .txt at the end ?

Comment: Check the update 2 above in answer. See if it works.

Comment: I got it to work only by writting : File file = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile() + ".txt");

Comment: That is fine. The code that i put is first checking if it already has .txt added in the filename if it does not have it then it adds it.

Comment: Yayyy, got it all now worked! Without you, I would be nothing! I APPERCIATE ALL HELP! I really mean it! Thank you! :)