# How would I create a string that has the same spaces and new lines as a text document?

Tags: java

I'm using a scanner class to read a text file. I want the string to have the same amount of spaces and new lines so that I can fit it into a JTextArea. Here's what I have so far:

```
public String getText(){
    String text = "";

    while(read.hasNextLine()){
        text += read.nextLine();

    }

    return text;
}
```

When I added + '\n' it just added white spaces and not new lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using a scanner class to read a text file.

Don't use a Scanner. There is no need to parse the file into lines of data.

Instead use a `Reader`, then you can use the `read(...)` method of a `JTextArea` to read the file:

```
JTextArea edit = new JTextArea(30, 60);
FileReader reader = new FileReader( "TextAreaLoad.txt" );
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
edit.read( br, null );
br.close();
```

Comment: I did not know that method existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `read.nextLine()` removes the `\n` character. So you have to add it back in with `text += read.nextLine() + "\n";`

So the full code will be:

```
public String getText(){
    String text = "";

    while(read.hasNextLine()){
         text += read.nextLine() + "\n";

    }

    return text;
}
```

**Edit:** As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483350/jtextarea-txt-txt-gettext-skips-n) you can replace `\n` with `\r\n` like `content = content.replaceAll("(?!\\r)\\n", "\r\n");`

Comment: Like I said, I tried doing that and it only added white spaces, not actual new lines.

Comment: Ah I see. As shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483350/jtextarea-txt-txt-gettext-skips-n) you can replace `\n` with `\r\n` like `content = content.replaceAll("(?!\\r)\\n", "\r\n");`

Answer (score 1):

You can actually add the newline back to your JTextArea by appending text string with the return value of `System.getProperty("line.separator");`. This is recommended as it returns the system-dependent line-feed and/or return carriage characters.

The `nextLine()` method actually strips any line-feeds and carriage return characters from your String.

Comment: There is no need to use the line.separator property. The Document always uses a "\n" to indicate a newline character.